# How to write to database asynchronously using future_promise in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to asynchronously write data to database(AWS postgres RDS) using DBI lib Shiny.
So far this is successful

```
data <- data.frame(id=threadr::uuid(), health_center_site_fact_id = "happy", total_patient=2)

write_user <- function(email, con) {
  uuid <- threadr::uuid()
  created_at = Sys.time()
  conn = con
    data.frame(id=uuid, health_center_site_fact_id = "happy", total_patient=2) %>%
    dbWriteTable(conn = conn, name = 'patientv',
                value = data,
                # overwrite = F,
                append = T,
                row.names = F) %>%
                print("database write successful :")

}
```

But when I introduce future_promise, I get a `Unhandled promise error: Invalid connection` error.

```
data <- data.frame(id=threadr::uuid(), health_center_site_fact_id = "happy", total_patient=2)

    write_user <- function(email, con) {
      uuid <- threadr::uuid()
      created_at = Sys.time()
      conn = con
      future_promise({

        data.frame(id=uuid, health_center_site_fact_id = "happy", total_patient=2) %>%
        dbWriteTable(conn = conn, name = 'patientv',
                    value = data,
                    # overwrite = F,
                    append = T,
                    row.names = F) %>%
                    print("database write successful :")
    
       })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't copy a database connection from the main process to a child process since the database connections are just pointers to places in memory, so in the child process that pointer will almost certainly point to garbage! You need to re-create the database connection in the child process.